# Sorbet signature for nested hash

Tags: sorbet

I have a method that parses YAML files. The returned object is a nested Hash, where the keys are always Strings and the leaf-values are always strings, e.g.

```
{
    "a" => "foo",
    "b" => {
        "c" => "bar",
        "d" => "baz"
    }
}
```

I don't know in advance how deep the hash is.

The closest I got to typing the return value was the following signature:

```
T.any(T::Hash[String,String], T::Hash[String,T::Hash[String, T.untyped]])
```

This is obviously a bad solution, since it doesn't check anything beneath the second nesting, but the documentation about custom types seems a bit sparse.

Is there any way to type nested hashes, using a custom type, nested types or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to do much more than what you got to at this point. Even though [`Shapes`](https://sorbet.org/docs/shapes) are supported, they are an experimental feature.

If you really want to go with hashes, you could express it as:

```rb
MyType = T.type_alias {T::Hash[String, T.any(String, T::Hash[String, T.untyped])]}
```

Alternatively, you could use a [`T::Struct`](https://sorbet.org/docs/tstruct):

```rb
class MyType < T::Struct
  const :key, String
  const :value, T.any(String, MyType)
end
```

You'd still have the uncertainty of what the type of the `value` is, but with [flow sensitivity](https://sorbet.org/docs/flow-sensitive), it should be easy to process the structure:

```rb
class Processor
  extend T::Sig
  
  sig {params(my_object: MyType).returns(String)}
  def process(my_object)
    key = my_object.key
    obj_value = my_object.value # this is needed for flow sensitivity below
    value = case obj_value
    when String
      value
    when MyType
      process(obj_value)
    else
      T.absurd(obj_value) # this makes sure that if you add a new type to `value`, Sorbet will make you handle it
    end
    return "key: #{key}, value: #{value}"
  end
end
```